# Differentiate $e^x+x^e$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My answer was $e^x+ex^{e-1}$. As I understand it, the derivative of $e^x $ is $e^x$. As for $x^e$, I made this $e(x^{e-1})$ and simplified from there. Where was my error?

Comment: You don't appear to have an error.

Comment: It's hard to understand you, but if you meant $$(e^x+x^e)'=e^x+ex^{e-1}=e(e^{x-1}+x^{e-1})$$ then you made no mistake.

Comment: Understood. Thank you. How do you get superscripts like that?

Comment: @aero26 To use mathmode use double \$ with your math stuff in between. To exponentiate like this $e^{2x}$ type e^{} enclose your variables in {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have differentiated the functions correctly.  There doesn't seems to be any error.